# Swapping elements of a sublist in a list in python

Tags: python, list, swap, sublist

I'm trying to change the following list of lists in Python by swapping the elements in the last position of each sublist. For example:

```
original_list = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']] 
new_list = [['1', '2', '9'], ['4', '5', '3'], ['7', '8', '6']]
```

Essentialy, the last element of each sublist is moved to the sublist to the right of it. So the last element of the first sublist goes to the second, the second goes to the third, and the third goes to the first.
Is there any way I can write a function that can do this for any list of 3 lists with 3 elements each?

Comment: Since toy problems like this are usually part of a homework exercise, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/843953)
|
[Open letter to students with homework problems](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166/39188)
|
[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

## Swap last elements

```
def swap_le(original_list):
    new_list = original_list.copy()
    for i in range(1, len(new_list)):
        new_list[i][-1], new_list[i-1][-1] = new_list[i-1][-1], new_list[i][-1]
    return new_list
```

call function and print.

```
original_list = [['1', '2', '3'], ['4', '5', '6'], ['7', '8', '9']] 
new_list = swap_le(original_list)
print(new_list)
```

### Results

`[['1', '2', '9'], ['4', '5', '3'], ['7', '8', '6']]`

## Short-code

```
def f(l):
    return l[-1:] + l[1:-1] + l[:1]
```

call f() and same result.
Hope this helps.

Comment: What's the point of making a shallow copy?

Comment: What makes you think the short code works?

Comment: First version doesn't work, either, doesn't give the results you claim.

Comment: When I tried this code, it gave me the following output:
[['1', '2', '6'], ['4', '5', '9'], ['7', '8', '3']]